# AngularJS - How to display message "Loading..." while the content is being loaded?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I found threads about this topic on SO, but it looks like my way of loading data isn't the best.

This is how the controller looks like:

```
app.controller("PostsCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', '$resource', 'Posts', 'Post', '$location', '$modal', '$timeout', function($scope, $http, $resource, Posts, Post, $location, $modal, $timeout) { 

    $scope.posts = Posts.query();

    ... some add/edit/delete code
```

When the page is loaded, the data from DB are not displayed immediately. How to display there the `loading...` message?

I've tried using `<div ng-if="loading">loading...</div>` in the view and

```
$scope.loading = true;
$scope.posts = Posts.query();
$scope.loading = false;
```

in the AngularJS controller, but this doesn't seems to be working.
I've also noticed that the `$scope.posts = Posts.query();` is executed every time when there's a call to the controller.

Is this a good (or AngularJS) way to solve this matter?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
$scope.loading = true;
$scope.posts = Posts.query(function ()  {
    $scope.loading = false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar

This thing is very nice, with this u don't need to wrap every request

just link in index.html and include dependecy in app.js and thats it